# REST API - "Extracted Text" property OneDrive

Tags: ocr, onedrive, live-sdk

How could I retrieve the extracted text property of images in OneDrive?
OneDrive runs an OCR on images and shows the extracted text. A user can also correct the mistakes in the text and update it (next time, it won't run OCR and will directly just show that)

I'm making a WP8.1 App and need API calls REST or LiveSDK to get this property.

If you browse for an image which has text on OneDrive and wait a few seconds, a extracted text property will appear on the left https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK9yn.png

I checked calls using Fiddler and there is an independent call for this extracted text  property - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pbfm.png  -- but how do I use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the OCR-extracted text isn't currently available through the REST API's.